# Func<T, TResult> access parameter

Tags: c#

I'm creating an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GroupAndSortBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
```

I would like to call this method from any collection:

```
myCollection.GroupAndSortBy(x => x.MyParam)
```

Where MyParam must be a string, because I want to use this in the method for alphabetic grouping.

Doing this, I should change the method signature to this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GroupAndSortBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, string> key)
```

The problem is that now I can't access the actual string that I'm passing as parameter, but I would like to do something like this:

```
source.GroupBy(key.ToLower().FirstOrDefault());
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Why do you need `.FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: Try this `source.GroupBy(x => key(x).ToLower())`

Comment: Why do you expect the result to be `IEnumerable<T>`? If you group items together then the result would be a set of groups, not a set of individual items. Can you please explain your goal?

Comment: FirstOrDefault has been added only for the question, I actually don't need it. The result is IEnumerable<T> but again, is for the question only, it's different in my real code. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `key` is a delegate, you should be *invoking* it, like this:

```
source.GroupBy(t => key(t).ToLower().FirstOrDefault());
```

This tells LINQ that in order to obtain a group key from a source value `t` of type `T` one needs to invoke `key(t)`, convert it to lower case, and grab the first letter, if any.

**Note:** You do not need to convert the whole key to lower case if all you want is the first letter:

```
source.GroupBy(t => char.ToLower(key(t).FirstOrDefault()));
```

Comment: You're totally right. Working 10h a day is stressing! Thank you :)

Comment: @xTuMiOx You are right, working only 10h a day is way too relaxing :-) :-) :-)

Comment: where is definition of `key`? (bit new to `Func` concept)

Comment: @Giorgi It's in OP's code: scroll the third snippet all the way to the right. The delegate type is defined [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Giorgi OP wants to do this: `var res = myList.GroupAndSortBy(person => person.Name)`, where `person => person.Name` becomes `Func<Person,string>` inside the call. When `GroupAndSortBy` calls `key(person)` LINQ ends up calling `person.Name`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight not following. ok maybe because I am new to `Func` concept. Will get familiar with it more, and later try more advanced uses of it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
var query = source.GroupBy(x => key(x).ToLower());
```

It is not clear to me why do you need `FirstOrDefault`. Do you want to use the first character only?

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` is there to grab the first letter.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, this is what it does, but I find it strange that OP would want that. Maybe he is using it my mistake.

Comment: I think all he wants to do is to group by first letter.

Comment: The problem was to get x => key(x) working, I totally forgot it's a delegate. I actually don't need FirstOrDefault, it was only for the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your `key` is a function (delegate) that returns a string, so you have to call it to get the string return value from it:

```
source.GroupBy(key().ToLower().FirstOrDefault());
```